# Adding Multiple Records at once - What type of form to use?

Tags: lightning

I have build a process to clone a record x number of times.  I have the user enter a number from 1 to 10 on the record and the function copies the record x number of times into an attribute.

I am trying to figure out the best way to display those records on one page so that they user can update each and save the record.

Currently, I am using a lightning:card with lightning:input and lightning:select fields.  The problem I am trying to avoid is having to maintain the select values in the code every time they change.

I have tried to use the recordeditform but could not figure out how to iterate the list of records.  I don't have an id to populate and I also need to get the default values for the fields populated as a starting point for the user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  thanks!!

Fred

Here is what I ended up doing..... I was able to use the recordEditForm without an ID.  I also was able to get the default values from the attribute.  This is what I ended up with:

```
<lightning:card title="Add account">
    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
        <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Group_Structure__c"  onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}">
            <lightning:messages/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" value="{!v.groupstructure.Name}"/>

            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Start_Date__c" value="{!v.groupstructure.Start_Date__c}"/>


            <lightning:button type="submit" name="Submit" label="submit" class="slds-m-top_medium"/>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
    </div>
</lightning:card>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use lightning:inputField tag inside lightning:recordEditForm. Using inputField will fetch picklist values from database.

Comment: Thanks Pavanaja.  I already have the attribute populated with what I need.  I don't copy all of the fields over.  But that part is working.  My issue is finding a way to create a form that is editible and displays my list from the attribute.  I updated my question to show what I am currently using.  thanks!

Comment: is your question is about getting picklist values directly from database instead of hard coding in code?

Comment: I figured it out.  I updated my original question with the code that I used. thanks!!!